# If I already have 9 eggs in my bag, what will I get from a Pokestop?

Tags: pokemon-go

Eggs are so easy to get, 80% of the time off of the pokestop. I'm full of eggs and wondering what Pokestops give you when you're full up.

Do they still give you eggs but end up not being able to take it? Or does the system replace it with another item?

Comment: Shafted, is what you get.

Answer (score 6):

Having a full egg bag would just take eggs out of the possible drop table.

This is similar to how great balls and ultra balls, along with the higher tier potions, are put *into* the drop table when they become available at certain levels.

Comment: Not entirely true, the eggs are separate "bonus drop".

Comment: What is a drop table or where can I read an explanation about it please?

Comment: It's basically a list of items that you are able to get from a pokestop. If you have the maximum number of eggs in your bag, it will just mark eggs as no longer valid for you to obtain until you have space for another.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you have 9 eggs you wont recieve any more from a pokestop. You also can't trow them away like other items from your bag. You have to incubate them to make space for a new egg, which you recieve from a pokestop- again only if you have less than 9 eggs.

I still get at least a total of 3 items from a pokestop. either 3 of the same kind or divided up between different items. Most of the time I recieve 4-6 in total. And sometimes even up to 9 in total. So my expirience would be that the eggs just get replaced.

Comment: Does that mean I'll have one less item if they happen to give me an egg or they'll replace it with another item? That's the real question. cause I want pokeballs the most and I hope it increase the amount of it.

Comment: I almost always have 9 eggs. I just checked I alwas get at least 3 items. most of the times aroun d 4-6 and sometimes up to 9. So I would say you just recieve other items instead.

Comment: @Kimuto considering pokestops don't seem to give out a set amount of items (I've seen as few as three, and as many as seven+), and that they aren't guaranteed to drop eggs even if you have room; it would be difficult to determine if your egg-bag being full results in an additional replacement item.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have 9 eggs and I tend to get the expected Poke' balls plus potions and revives.